# Type Mismatch in conditional

Tags: c#, function, vba, ms-access

I am new at VBA, but i have been programming a lot of C#. My issue here is that i keep getting "Runtime error 13. Type Mismatch" error in my VBA function.

I am extracting data from a Table in access and then trying to filter some of the data.

My function looks like this:

```
Function FlowType(deliveryAdrID As String, deliverType As String, note As String) As String
    If (note = "*J") Then
        FlowType = "Weekend"
    ElseIf (deliveryAdrID = "62242" & deliverType = "H") Then
        FlowType = "AirGotland"
    ElseIf (deliveryAdrID <> "62242" & deliverType = "H") Then
        FlowType = "Air"
    Else
        FlowType = "Standard"
    End If
End Function
```

Why do I get this error? The error occurs on this line:

```
ElseIf (deliveryAdrID = "62242" & deliverType = "H") Then
```

Comment: & is a concatenation operator, not logical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is because you use `&`, instead of `And`. The ampersand symbol is an operator to concatenate strings, whereas `And` is a Boolean operator. So, change your comparisons like so:

```
ElseIf ((deliveryAdrID = "62242") And (deliverType = "H")) Then
```

With `&`, (assuming both conditions are satisified) the expression you are using will evaluate to

```
ElseIf ("TrueTrue") Then
```

which doesn't make sense since "TrueTrue" is not Boolean.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Worked perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You declare `deliveryAdrID` as Double, but you try to assign a `String` to it:

```
deliveryAdrID = "62242"
```

That's a Type Mismatch, as VBA tries to tell you. ;)

So, just use

```
deliveryAdrID = 62242
```

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks for the heads up on that. But thats not the issue. The problem still occurs. i tried using double and that didnt even fire the function. When i edited it back i forgot to edit the method parameter.